# How to remove default media buttons for MediaPlayer/SMTC class? C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, media

[image]

I want to remove this UIElements, how can i do this?

Comment: looks like the screenshot is from taskbar app window preview, you want to remove the buttons from taskbar?

Comment: yes, it is from taskbar.

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Comment: Hello, the buttons in the preview window of the taskbar are mainly for users to perform shortcut operations. Appears when the UWP application plays video or audio through `MediaPlayer` and is integrated with `SMTC`. There is currently no API to remove this set of shortcut buttons (but it can be disabled). Why do you want to remove this set of buttons, or do you accept the solution of disabling shortcut buttons?

Comment: requirement is like this, that is why wanted to remove those. but it seems we cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to remove default button provided by SMTC.